# In a maven project, is it possible to use a plugin just built within the same project?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Suppose you have some sort of input files which are to be processed in some custom way (even the file format is very particular to the package of files in question).

To process them I decide to make a maven plugin, which happens to be useful only in the context of these files.

Is it possible to have them all (the afore mentioned files and source code for the plugin) in one project, build the plugin, run the plugin over the input files and collect its output as *the output* of this project?

Comment: Sounds a little bit weird. Why not releasing the plugin and afterwards simply using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't, because Maven resolves plugin classpath on start.

However you can create separate modules, first being a plugin and second would use that plugin to process files. Both modules can be invoked from parent pom.

Comment: In most cases I used the latest release of my plugin to build the upcoming release.